# Is STATE of Client or Server depends on Information (In REST point of view)?

Tags: api, rest, http

I am really getting confused with the word STATE in REST

1. What exactly state means in REST? Is that something `a form based on the information of data?`
2. State of the APPLICATION changes means what?

Please explain what exactly `state` means in REST with a simple example by using REST CLIENT REQUEST & REST SERVER RESPONSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary authority for REST is [Roy Fielding's dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), which defines the term.

The discussion of the [Data View](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_3_3) would likely be the best starting point:

> An application's state is therefore defined by its pending requests, the topology of connected components (some of which may be filtering buffered data), the active requests on those connectors, the data flow of representations in response to those requests, and the processing of those representations as they are received by the user agent.

> An application reaches a steady-state whenever it has no outstanding requests; i.e., it has no pending requests and all of the responses to its current set of requests have been completely received or received to the point where they can be treated as a representation data stream. For a browser application, this state corresponds to a "web page," including the primary representation and ancillary representations, such as in-line images, embedded applets, and style sheets. The significance of application steady-states is seen in their impact on both user-perceived performance and the burstiness of network request traffic.